# Looking for short comics about boy sent for a quest for leaf

Tags: story-identification, comics, webcomics

I am looking for a short comics that I've seen long time ago somewhere in the web.

The comics is about a boy who falls in love with a girl, but the girl is a bitch. She orders the boy to get extremely rare leaf/flower as a token of his love to her. The point is - she does not love him back and does not want him around/wants to use him. The boy embarks to a quest and travels around the globe (which is shown on several snapshot-frames) and finally gets back with the leaf/flower. The girl despises the gift and show her true face.  At first boy is heartbroken because his efforts were meaningless, then he realises that the quest made him a better person/hero and his better off without bitch-girl.

It is set in fantasy world and really short (around 20 frames max, single image) and without typical speech bubbles (only symbols).

Any chanses that someone know what I am talking about and have the web address of the comics or the image file itself?

Comment: This was the entire plot of Stardust

Comment: I was going to say Stardust too, but there are enough differences (and enough major plot points missed) to suggest that it isn't that. Not to mention I don't think Stardust was ever released in any kind of web format.

Comment: It was single image comics strip. Like 5 frames of introduction, 10 frames of hero's journey and ending.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like ["My Hero"](http://comicsalliance.com/my-hero-silent-adventure-comic-matt-rhodes-anthology-project-mass-effect-artist/) by Matt Rhodes.

[image]

Comment: It differs from my description (and how I remembered it) but it is exactly it! Thanks!